# Parse XML file with multiple XML tags using SAX parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse a XML file with multiple XML declarations.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/KDD/ID/1">
```

and I'm getting the following exception

```
the processing target matching  "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed
```

My parser works perfectly if there is a single xml declaration.  The XML file is very large and I cannot possibly go and remove all the tags. Is there any way to do this

Comment: Where are the multiple XML declarations?

Comment: One xml declaration followed by several lines of tags and then again a xml declaration .. This repeats

Answer (score 1):

A well-formed XML Document may have only one XML Declaration and one Root Element.

A well-formed XML External Parsed Entity may have more than one root note, but still may have only one XML Declaration.

If you want this to parse, you're going to have to preprocess your input -- break it up into separate documents, or remove the extra XML Declaration -- or fix whatever's generating the document in the first place so it produces correct XML, which is in the long run the better answer.